How to construct a type which is the union of value from a const array?
I have an array:
const specialNumbers = [1, 10, 20, 50] as const; // type: readonly [1, 10, 20, 50]

I would like a type (ex: SpecialNumber) that is the union of the values in the arrays.
For example to be used as:
const getSpecialNumber = (): SpecialNumber => { // SpecialNumber = 1 | 10 | 20 | 50
  // ...
}

How to construct SpecialNumber from specialNumbers?

This question is similar to: Define a union type from an array of strings. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"[1, 10, 20, 50] as const; // type: readonly [2, 4, 6, 8]" - something is off there

@jonrsharpe, that's the answer I was looking for but it didn't appear in my search. Maybe because the question was not generic enough (the title only mention strings)

@Berg Oops good catch, I'm updating it

To get the union of the values, you can do:
type SpecialNumber = (typeof specialNumbers)[number];

